# Kartik grid yii2 add the data in cells form row

Tags: yii2, grid, sum, kartik-v

I saw the examples where kartik grid add the data of the column and show in the footer. But what I want is to add the data in row cell of the same column and show it in the next next. Something like this :

```
Row  Sum
7.5  22.5 
7.5
7.5
```

[image]

Comment: Sum will be same for all ?

Comment: I will use rowspan (group feature of kartik grid) in sum column